# delete object element within an array

Tags: javascript

I have an object, and within the object, i need to `delete` the `address` from the array of objects using javascript.

```
 obj = {
        "name":1,
        "Details":[
            {
              "mname":"text here",
              "sname":"text here",
              "address":"text",
              "saddress":"text"
            }
        ]
      }
```

I have tried the following, but no luck:

```
delete obj.Details.address
```

and

```
delete obj.Details[0].address
```

Comment: The latter should work with no problem

Comment: There must have been something wrong with the way i might have structured the project, but the latter is now working, thanks for your help everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your object structure is wrong

```
  obj = {
    "name":1,
    "Details":[
        {
          "mname":"text here",
          "sname":"text here",
          "address":"text",
          "saddress":"text"
        }
    ]
  }
```

it should be "address":"text", in string format then

```
delete obj.Details[0].address
```

will work.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem!

Comment: my mistake,thats was a typo, the quotes are there

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this don't work?

```
delete obj.Details[0].address
```

I've just tried in the chrome console and this works. Maybe you're not debugging correctly

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the `adress` property of all the objects inside the `Details` array, then do it using [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) like this:

```
obj.Details.forEach(function(detail) {
    delete detail.address;
});
```

Or using an old `for` loop like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < obj.Details.length; i++) {
    delete obj.Details[i].adress;
}
```